# What is the word that sounds like "caromize" which means "cook a dish until we can reduce the juice in that dish to being viscous"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, pronunciation, food

OK, once I watched the Master Chef program and I heard people use a word that sounds like "*caromize*" to express the meaning of “cook a dish until the juices of the dish has reduced and is viscous”.

For example, you season your raw meat in a pan and then pour coconut water into meat. Then you cook it until all the coconut juice in your pan has reduced and becomes viscous.

Then I can say "*cook the meat until it got caromized*". I am not sure *caromize* is the word.

So, what is the word that sounds like "*caromize*" which expresses the meaning of "*cook a dish until we can reduce the juice in that dish to being viscous*"?

Comment: The "carmelize" pronounciation is a US thing (well, I don't know about Canada), ie, they skip a syllable. The rest of the native English speaking world says cara-mel-ize. It used to confuse me, when I heard US cooking shows, as it conjured a vision of Carmelite nuns saying prayers for the dish. The US has many different sounding culinary terms.

Comment: Re the pronunciation of "caramel", I regularly hear "car-mul", "care-mul", "care-uh-mul", and "care-uh-mel", with the pronunciation of "caramelize" following suit.  And likely people (including myself) may choose one other depending on the context.  I don't regard any of the four as being better or worse, save that "car-mul" tends to come across as a bit snooty.

Comment: Of possible interest: [Is “sealing in the flavor” an actual thing?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/59807/is-sealing-in-the-flavor-an-actual-thing)

Comment: The other answer is excellent, of course: the apparent US English tendency to swallow syllables. But I do think there are some potentially subtler issues, as my friend's "mandolin", as kitchen implement, which, as an amateur musician, seriously confused me... but/and after suitable googling found that the kitchen implement is "mandoline". Hilarious, all 'round...

Comment: It is a great shame that DrSpleen's answer was changed into a comment. I'm not saying it was anything as good as tchrist's but it did help to confirm that the  three syllable pronunciation exists. Sometimes the "weak" and "amusing" answers help the stronger ones to shine.  Just saying.

Comment: There were candy bar commercials a few years ago in the U.S. in which basketball star Shaquille O'Neal argued the pronunciation of "caramel" back and forth with a youth.  YouTube hosts at least one commercial from this campaign.  In the one I just looked up, Shaq and the kid both seem to have reversed their positions from what I remember.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Definition of *caramelize*

That word is *caramelize*, to cook something until its sugars turn to caramel at around 410° F. Recipes will often call for sautéing onions until they caramelize, for example.

[image: Wikipedia article picture of caramelization]

The [Wikipedia article on *caramelization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caramelization) from which the image above was taken says that it is:

> the browning of sugar, a process used extensively in cooking for the resulting nutty flavor and brown color. As the process occurs, volatile chemicals are released, producing the characteristic caramel flavor. Like the Maillard reaction, caramelization is a type of non-enzymatic browning. However, unlike the Maillard reaction, caramelization is pyrolysis, as opposed to reaction with amino acids.

### Origins

The OED says that English took the word *caramel* from French and that they in turn adapted it from the Spanish, Portuguese, and Italian word *caramelo*. Larousse says that the French took it from the Spanish and that the Spanish took it from the Portuguese, and the DRAE confirms that the Spanish got it from the Portuguese. But somewhere in Iberia the trail grows cold, and the OED ultimately says that it is of uncertain origin, providing this note:

> Scheler suggests that the Spanish represents Latin *calamellus* little tube, in reference to its tubular form; Mahn thinks it from medieval Latin *cannamella* sugar-cane: an Arabic source is conjectured by Littré.

### Variable Pronunciation

Actual pronunciation of the word *caramelization* varies between /ˈkɑɹməˌlaɪz/ with three syllables (“karma lies”) and /ˈkeɹəməˌlaɪz/ with four syllables (“carry m’ lies”).¹ The shorter three-syllable version is probably the more common of the two in North America except on the East Coast and in the South, although either could be heard pretty much anywhere across the continent.

This is because there are **two different underlying pronunciations** for *caramel* possible: one has three syllables, /ˈkeɹəˌmɛl/, and the other has only two syllables, /ˈkɑɹməl/.
[Wiktionary claims of *caramel*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caramel) that:

> Both the two syllable and the three syllable pronunciations are very common in all regions of the United States, but the trisyllabic pronunciation is more common than the disyllabic one in the South (excluding western Texas), northern New Jersey, eastern New York, and New England, while the disyllabic one is more common than the trisyllabic one in other regions.

Neither pronunciation should be confused for *Carmel* as in *Carmel-by-the-Sea* which is contrastively stressed on the second syllable, so /kɑɹˈmɛl/.  This does, however, suggest a path towards forcing a particular pronunciation if one is so inclined.

### Forcing a Particular Pronunciation

You normally can’t tell from reading something how the writer expected it to be pronounced, but in some forms of verse you can.  Here’s a bit of doggerel to force the reader into one or the other of the two pronunciations.

#### With a “Missing” Syllable

Using a bouncy [limerick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limerick_(poetry)):

> *There was a young lady from Wheaton
>
>   Who swore that the best thing she’d eaten
>
>              From Carmelite nuns
>
>              Was caramelized buns
>
>   With pockets to hide all the meat in.*

That one demands the “ca**rm**elized” pronunciation that’s missing a syllable to match *Ca**rm**elite* and to have the right stresses and syllable count to fit the meter. There is no sound at all between the *r* and the *m* in both those words. People who say “ca**rm**el” with two syllables (usually) also say “ca**rm**elized” with three.

#### With an “Extra” Syllable

Using the flickering [trisyllabic assonances of Tolkien’s *Errantry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errantry):

> *Columbus sailed his caravels
>
>          In parallels across the seas
>
>   In search of spicy caramels
>
>          And fairy shells and colonies.*

That one demands the “ca**r*a*m**els” pronunciation with the extra syllable to match *caravels, parallels, fairy shells* — and to have the right stresses and syllable count to fit this more exotic (and much more difficult!) verse form. There is a schwa sound between the *r* and the *m*. People who say “ca**r*a*m**el” with three syllables say “ca**r*a*m**elized” with four.

#### Footnotes

1. Don’t worry too much about the broad phonemic transcriptions; these represent phonemes only, not exact sounds. Some speakers may even realize that phonetically as [ˈkæə̯ɹəmɪ̈ˌlaɪz].

Comment: Though it should be noted that the term does not necessarily imply "boiling down" a liquid, but, literally, means cooking a sugar-containing substance until some of the sugar is converted to caramel.  In the OP's example the meat does not caramelize, but rather the sugar in the coconut juice.

Comment: Note that *caramel* and its derivatives are almost universally pronounced as *carmel* /kɑɹməl/ in the US today.

Comment: @StoneyB - I would disagree.  Both pronunciations (and several in-between) are used in the US, often in a context-dependent fashion..

Comment: @HotLicks Perhaps I move in too narrow a circle; but I haven't heard anybody but me say *caramel* for years.

Comment: @StoneyB - I think my ears are more sensitive than most to minor variations in such pronunciations.

Comment: in my experience "caramel" is the more typical, or "correct" pronunciation. I have only ever heard yankees use "car-mel". Much the way pecans are said as "pee-cans" by some when the correct way is "pe-cons".

Comment: @StoneyB: this is very regional. [See this map](http://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2013/06/pecan-caramel-crawfish-food-dialect-maps/276603/). Basically, the three-syllable pronunciation is used in much of the South and Northeast, and everywhere else uses two syllables.

Comment: @PeterShor Hmm ... I wonder if there's some selection bias in that survey, cuz I grew up in East Alabama in the 50s and 60s and heard *carmel* everywhere. But then perhaps it's only my own vexation bias.

Comment: @StoneyB: since the South is only light blue, that means that there are still lots of people using the three-syllable pronunciation, which probably your includes your area of East Alabama. If it were unanimous, it would be dark blue (see the pop/soda/coke map).

Comment: @PeterShor Jes one more reason to go back home . . .

Comment: @Margana Yes, meat contains sugars but meat browns primarily by the [Maillard reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maillard_reaction), not by caramelization. And I disagree on "carry m'lies" in the UK. I've never heard anything other than "ca-ruh-muh-lize" or "ca-ruh-mell-ize" ("ca" as in "cat", "uh" as in the second syllable of "lemon", "mell" rhymes with "tell").

Comment: @DavidRicherby. Ok. Thanks. I was wrong on both accounts, then. Although I thought I'd tried to reproduce your pronunciation using tchrist's 4 syllable spelling. Your comments are much better than mine, and I'll remove mine so as not to get in your way.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The “spelt out” version, *carry m’lies* was meant only to be a coarse approximation. I hesitated quite some time in deciding what to use for the vowel in the third syllable, since to me it seems less reduced than the one in the second syllable—so maybe the [ɛ] of *tell* has there been reduced to the [ɨ] of *spott**e**d, **e**mission, Ros**e**s.  But a schwa /ə/ seemed ok for both phonemes. For the first vowel, only a few North Americans still have [æ] as in *cat* for [æɹ] in *carry, marry, Larry*; the rest of us merge all three of *Mary–merry–marry* into [eɹ] or [ɛɹ]. Don’t you?

Comment: @tchrist I'm not north-American and I pronounce Mary, merry and marry with three different vowels. But for me, and I don't think this is restricted to British pronunciation, the *second* vowel of "caramelize" (when pronounced with four syllables) is very different from the second vowel of "carry".

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think you may be focusing too much on the lame spelling pronunciations, but this does illustrate why they are utterly useless for conveying how something is actually said. You also may be underestimating the effects of reduction in connected speech. The IPA is infinitely better, but do remember that the broad /phonemic/ transcriptions are just that: broad. Even the *Roses–Rosa’s* minimal pair is controversial, and not universally observed. How they are actually pronounced [phonetically] varies greatly between speakers and situations.

Comment: Erm... *The second ditty, which I like / ('tis very clever) and full of sprite / Has “caramels” not “caramelite” /* In other words, where is the four syllable *caramelized*? If I am supposed to read the *caramelized* in "caramelized buns" as three syllables, then where is the four syllable version? (Many apologies for  my feeble feeble attempt to emulate your tribute to Tolkien)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I’ve edited that section to clarify what I meant.  The point is that some people say *carmel* and *carmelize* with nothing between the *r* and *the *m* just like with Carmelite, but others say *car**a**mel* and *car**a**melize* with an extra syllable in each. The meter and rhyme in each respective verse, along with similar words, was an attempt to force that particular reading, but I’ve now added a longer explanation of what I meant beneath each ditty. I know this makes little sense to a Romance speaker used to *caramelo* but the *carmel* pronunciation is common in North America.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Brits say caramelized with four syllables too. But your mini-explanation now makes more sense. I'm just sorry I can't upvote more than once.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, the Brits do indeed use four syllables in *caramelized*. I reckon that the three-syllable version is now more common in North America, perhaps because of Californian bias in Hollywood productions seen everywhere. However, no one will look at you funny for using the four-syllable version here, and that version is more common the further east you go; see [the maps references by Peter Shore](http://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2013/06/pecan-caramel-crawfish-food-dialect-maps/276603/). In the Midwest, one gets delicious peanut-coated “carmel apples” in autumn.